# Given three coordinates (a,b,c), (d,e,f), and (l,m,n), what is the center of the circle in the 3D plane (h,k,i) that contains these three points.

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I have tried the following:
$$(a-h)^2+(b-k)^2+(c-i)^2=r^2$$
$$(d-h)^2+(e-k)^2+(f-i)^2=r^2$$
$$(l-h)^2+(m-k)^2+(n-i)^2=r^2$$
Subtracted equation 2 from 1, equation 3 from equation 2, and equation 3 from equation 1 to get:
$$2(a-d)h+2(b-e)k+2(c-f)i=a^2-d^2+b^2-e^2+c^2-f^2$$
$$2(d-l)h+2(e-m)k+2(f-n)i=d^2-l^2+e^2-m^2+f^2-n^2$$
$$2(a-l)h+2(b-m)k+2(c-n)i=a^2-l^2+b^2-m^2+c^2-n^2$$
Closer inspection revealed to me that the left side formed a 3 x 3 matrix and the left a 3 by 1 matrix.
Tried solving for $(h,k,i)$ by taking the inverse of the left side matrix and multiplying that by the right side 3 by 1 matrix, but it turns out the left side matrix's rows are dependent, so the determinant of the left side matrix is 0 (singular matrix); hence, no inverse.
Please guide me as to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Drop perpendiculars from two segments joining pairs of the given points and find where they meet.

Comment: @Weltschmerz Thanks. That was the first thing that popped into my mind as I solved this problem. The one thing is this is in 3D so the perpendicular has to found in the common plane and I would prefer to stick to the original Cartesian planes. The main reason is I am writing some code and do not want it to be extremely complex. (i.e. It can have large expressions and vector operations not real vector math.) It is less about the circle, it is more about the center.

Comment: The first three equations are the sphere equation with each of the three points substituted. You have to add an additional constraint, either the $r$ is minimised, or $(h,k,i)$ falls on the common plane of the three points.

Comment: @peterwhy (h,k,i) falls on the common plane of the three points because it is a circle.

Comment: @HighEnergy I know, so your system of subtracted equation did not include this information. And there is an answer below about this.

Comment: @HighEnergy So why does finding perpendicular planes not work for you? You can find the perpendicular bisector planes of any two pairs of vertices, and find the common plane of the three vertices, and find the intersections of the three planes.

Comment: Did you use the fact that the circle is in the plane with the three points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For points $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$, their perpendicular bisector can be found by:
$$\begin{align*}
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2+(z-c)^2 &= (x-d)^2 + (y-e)^2 + (z - f)^2\\
a^2-2ax+b^2-2by+c^2 -2cz &= d^2 - 2dx + e^2 - 2ey + f^2 - 2fz\\
2(a-d)x +2(b-e)y + 2(c-f)z &= a^2+b^2+c^2-d^2-e^2-f^2
\end{align*}$$

Do the same and find the perpendicular bisector of $(d,e,f)$ and $(l,m,n)$.

For three points $(a,b,c)$, $(d,e,f)$ and $(l,m,n)$, their common plane $px+qy+r = z$ can be found by:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&1\\d&e&1\\l&m&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
p\\q\\r
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
c\\f\\n
\end{pmatrix}$$
This might have some problem if their common plane is perpendicular with the $xy$-plane, but you can always change to use $x$ or $y$ to be the subject of the equation and try to solve again. You are using a computer anyway.

Now you have three equations in the form of $tx + uy + vz = w$, and you should be able to solve for their intersection $(x,y,z) = (h,k,i)$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your equations don't capture the totality of conditions.

In fact, at present, you have three unknowns but, as you have remarked, only two independent equations.

This situation reflects that you have one degree of freedom. Indeed, what you have expressed is constraints on spheres, and there is an infinite number of spheres passing through 3 points in 3D space.

The supplementary condition you need to add is the coplanarity of the points and the center of the circle; this coplanarity is given by the nullity of the determinant:

$$\left|\begin{matrix}a&d&l&h\\b&e&m&k\\c&f&n&i\\1&1&1&1\end{matrix}\right|=0$$

(see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Coplanar.html).

Solving this system of equations in 2016 does not rely on hand calculation but on the  use of  a computer algebra system (Maple, Mathematica...).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a faster way is to use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line), $H=3G+2O$.
If we have to find the circumcenter of $ABC$, we may compute the projection of $C$ on the $AB$-line and the projection of $B$ on the $AC$-line through scalar products, or by finding the minimum of a squared distance (they are the same approach, indeed). So the orthocenter $H$ can be found by intersecting two lines. 
The centroid is very easy to compute by just considering the arithmetic mean of the coordinates of the vertices. So $O$ can be found through $O=\frac{H-3G}{2}$.

> An alternative and faster approach is to exploit the fact that the [barycentric coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html) of the circumcenter (i.e. the coefficients
>   $(u,v,w)$ such that $O=uA+vB+wC$) just depends on the squared distances
>   $AB^2,AC^2,BC^2$, that also in the 3d-case are straightforward to compute through the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Your proposal to use barycentric coordinates is certainly the most efficient ; the problem is that very few people know them. Besides, I would like to say that your relationship $H=3G+2O$ is not exact (H is not between $0$ and $G$). As you want to express $O$, the formula for $O$ is $0=3G-2H$.